# how can I hydrate a dataframe of tweets id's in python

Tags: python, twitter, pyspark, tweepy, twython

I have a dataframe in pyspark called tweets and I have in it the column "tweet_id" and i want to get the full tweets using their id and put them in a new dataframe (can i do that using tweepy,twarc or twython?).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Tweepy for handeling tweets with Python. Here are the [docs](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/index.html).

If you want to hydrate a tweet id with its metadata there is a method for that purpose: `api.get_status()`. As the docs describes:

> Returns a single status specified by the ID parameter.

You'll find the information about the method and all the parameters available [here](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.get_status).